# sort result by count of string occurence in multiple fields per row

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create (some sort-of) full-text search on a MySQL DB: I want to find occurrences of a string 'abc' in 2 fields `TITLE` and `DESCRIPTION` and sort the result by the number of occurrences (per row), preferably weighted, i.e. every 'abc' found in `TITLE` counts 2x that of a match in `DESCRIPTION`.

Is this possible at all in one (possibly long and ugly) query or will I have to create some word-index table?

My approach so far finds the occurrences, but doesn't sort, yet alone weight. (I do the latter in PHP but this is starting to become very expensive):

```
SELECT * FROM CONTENT WHERE (`TITLE` like '%abc%' OR DESCRIPTION like '%abc')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` to shorten the string by the number of search hits.  That way you can count the number of occurances of a string in a column.  You can put a factor in front of each occurance count to increase its weight.  This example counts `col1` twice:

```
select  *
,       (
          2 * (char_length(col1) - char_length(replace(col1,'abc',''))) +
          (char_length(col2) - char_length(replace(col2,'abc','')))
        ) / char_length('abc') as Occurances
from    YourTable
order by
        Occurances desc
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/837a4/3/0)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT 2*(LENGTH(`TITLE`)-LENGTH(REPLACE(`TITLE`,'abc',''))) + 
         (LENGTH(DESCRIPTION)-LENGTH(REPLACE(DESCRIPTION,'abc',''))) sort_num,
       c.* FROM CONTENT c
WHERE (`TITLE` like '%abc%' OR DESCRIPTION like '%abc')
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: +1 first right answer.  You're right to omit the division by the length of the search string if it's just for sorting.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I would have not worked that out in 10 years! Works a total treat :)